# Why is my use of the <img> 'onload' event handler working sporadically?

Tags: javascript, html

The code below, works ... sometimes, but I don't know why it doesn't work all the time.

I'm trying to determine how many people press the "Buy Now" PayPal button that's on different webpages.

Currently, each page on the site fetches a 43 byte 1x1 gif from unique locations (thanks to `mod_rewrite`) that is easily grep'able in the Apache access log.  My thinking was that if I could change the URL for that image with javascript, I could track the click in the access log while still having the browser's forward and back buttons work.

The code below (`Override_Form_OnClick()`) looks for a form on the page (there's only one) and attaches a handler (`my_shopping()`) to the form's `onclick` handler.

The `my_shopping()` handler then updates the image resource named `my_stats` (again, there's only one), attaches the form element's `submit` function to the image's `onload` handler, then returns false so that the form doesn't get submitted until the new image loads.

That's the intention, but it doesn't always log the new image in the access log.  Granted, I've only been testing it in Chrome using the dev tools, so maybe it's an issue with other browsers?

```
<script>
function my_shopping(onload_handler, shopping_tag) {
    'use strict';
    var my_img_elements = document.getElementsByName('my_stats'),
        my_img_url,
        i,
        len;
    len = my_img_elements.length;
    if (len > 1) {
        alert("Multiple my_stats elemetns on page: only expected 1.");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        my_img_url = my_img_elements[i].src;
        my_img_url = my_img_url.replace(".gif", "." + shopping_tag + ".gif");
        my_img_elements[i].onload = onload_handler;
        my_img_elements[i].src = my_img_url;
    }
    return false;
}

function Override_Form_OnClick() {
    'use strict';
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('form'),
        element,
        i,
        len;
    len = elements.length;

    if (len > 1) {
        alert("Multiple 'form' elements on page: only expected 1.");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        element = elements[i];
        element.onclick = function () { my_shopping(element.submit, "shopping.PayPal") };
    }
    return true;
}

Override_Form_OnClick();
</script>
```

The policy of the website has a strong preference for using only javascript.

Comment: is it possible that the images are cached?

Comment: Try assigning the `.src` before `.onload`. Those images are probably already loaded, before you change their `.src`, since they have a `.src`. By the way, ever heard of `i++`. Your `for` loops should look more like `for(var i=0,l=my_image_elements.length; i<l, i++)`. That way you can reuse `i` and `l` in other loops.

Comment: @PHPglue Could you elaborate on 'probably already loaded' ... as for the awkard `i += 1`, an online lint program complained of `i++`, and `len` is evaluated before the loop starts.

Comment: @stevemarvell I don't see how: the users would have had to click the form/link already to get the image in the cache.  The purchases are one time things which wouldn't have people clicking all the time anyway.

Comment: `my_img_url = my_img_elements[i].src`

Comment: @PHPglue Uhh ... I'm being obtuse.  I'm doing a read-modify-write on the url.  You're making a point about the `.src` being set already (it's set in the static html), but I don't know what point your making.

Comment: The `Image` Object has a `.src`, which has completed, so. `onload` fires as as soon as the `.src` is loaded into the cache. If you already have a source in your cache under that `Image` object, `onload` fires.

Comment: @PHPglue I thought as much; reversing the assignment seems to help.  Does the assignment to `.src` clear the previous `onload` signal?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work. Let me know.

```
for(var i=0,l=my_img_elements.length; i<l; i++){
  var mi = my_img_elements[i], ni = new Image;
  ni.src = mi.src = mi.src.replace(".gif", "." + shopping_tag + ".gif");
  ni.onload = onload_handler;
}
```

Comment: Pedantic, but: Even though it will be hoisted, I find it cleaner only to declare a variable once; I would put that declaration outside of the loop.

Comment: @tomas. Which variable? `mi` has to be inside the loop to work.

Comment: @phpglue "mi". But that redeclaration will not cause an error. It's just semantics ;)

Comment: @tomas. Yeah, as long as `mi = my_img_elements[i]` inside the loop, you're Right.

Comment: Switching the order makes the code work ~ 3-5% of the time.  unfortunately, not a solution.